# Data Mapping/Transformation

Tags: python, math

I have literature data (the blue data in the attached image) and generated data (the red data).

I would like to map the blue data to the same x-data range as the red data.

The end point is the same for each data set (2.87cm to be specific) but the starting point is different.

I know this is more of a math question, but if someone has an idea how to map this in python, I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

[image: enter daimage description here]

Comment: I don't understand what you need...

Comment: basically stretch the blue data over the same range as the red data, while keeping the end point the same. Does that make sense?

Comment: and with stretching, I only mean stretching along the x axis.

Comment: do you have the data in a list? a numpy array?

Comment: In a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this is what you want... your question is not clear at all.

```
import numpy as np

# having two arrays ameri and rans, each with 2 dims

shift = rans[:, 0].min() - ameri[:, 0].min()
scale = (
    (rans[:, 0].max() - rans[:, 0].min()) # rans' x-range size
        /
    (ameri[:, 0].max() - ameri[:, 0].min()) # ameri's x-range size
)

ameri[:, 0] = (ameri[:, 0] + shift) * scale
```

This will shift `ameri` to the lowest x-value and then scale it to the same range as `rans`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed.

Thank you for your help and fast response!